# Android Splash Screen to FragmentActivity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, fragment, splash-screen

Is it possible to open a FragmentActivity after Splash screen?

I want to open the FragmentActivity / Fragment after the Splash screen but I get following Error:

> Unable to find explicit activity class {com.**********.MainActivity};
>   have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

My splash screen:

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

    private final int SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH = 3000;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this,Juli.class);
                SplashScreen.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
                SplashScreen.this.finish();
            }
        }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH);
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
   <activity
        android:name="com.test.tab.SplashScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Manifest add:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <!-- Splash screen -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.test.tab.SplashScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!-- Main activity -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.test.tab.Juli"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Every activity which you want use must be declared in manifest - http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html